# How to print the char, integer, float and double values without using format specifiers in c

Tags: c

I want to print the char, int, float and double values without using format specifiers in my c program.
I can able to print the string using the below code:

```
char s[] = "Hello\n";
fprintf(stdout, s);
```

how can I print the other data type values?

Comment: You can use **cout << s;** in c++.

Comment: why would anyone in the world want to do that?

Comment: Well in C, it is the way to print different datatypes. C libraries are written like that, therefore, for what you want, you will have write your own library from the scratch!

Comment: Why do I need to be re-invention?

Comment: If you really need this for whatever program you are writing, then you (almost certainly) should not be writing it in C.

Comment: it is homework/educational, to learn how this can be done by yourself, and then use the real thing as a giveaway.

Comment: I doubt that this was given as homework considering that it is impossible to do this generically in C, unless I am missing something pretty significant.  Also considering that OP intends to print strings by calling `fprintf(stdout, s)` seems to suggest he is hoping for a function that will make it "easy to print ints".

Comment: While I'm exploring interview questions I came across this problem. @Andrey

Comment: ahh, those silly "interview questions". Write a programm in C without using standard C-functionallity :-( Can anybody in the business explain to me, what INTENTION is behind this kind of question; what knack shall be evaluated with this? "do as commanded" vs "rebellious"?

Comment: I do not see why people are interpreting this as a request for any sort of polymorphism or overloading. The question does not ask for a way to print the different types using an identical call, just for ways to print different types. This can be done using different code for each type.

Comment: The OP specifically says "without using format specifiers" in his post.

Comment: @Andrey: So? `PrintInt(x); PrintFloat(y); PrintDouble(z);` does not use format specifiers. They are asking not to use format specifiers because they do not want to use the built-in library formatters. That is not unusual for a class assignment or for an environment without a full library available. The question does not contain any statement requesting to do this through a single form of function call.

Comment: In that case it seems clear that `void PrintInt(int x) { printf("%d",x); }`, etc. are the right answers considering `fprintf(stdout,...)` was acceptable in OP's post.  Anyway this is probably a silly discussion at this point because the question is ambiguous in the first place, and probably (IMO) mis-copied or mis-interpreted from the supposed interview it came from.

Comment: @Andrey: That code uses a format specifier. The question specifically asks not to do that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what, then, do you think of OP's code?  As far as I can tell he thinks that the `printf` family "allow you to print a string without a format specifier" by passing a `char*`, which is not even true, and he is asking for functions that allow you to print other formats "without a format specifier" in the same way.

Comment: @Andrew: The question does not ask for functions that allow you to print other formats “in the same way”. Those are words you added; they are not in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print a `char`, use:

```
fputc(c, stream)
```

(If the stream is `stdout`, you can use `putchar(c)`.)

To print an `int`:

- If the `int` is negative, print “-”.
- Calculate the individual digits of the integer. This can be done either by calculating the digits from least significant to most significant and saving them in a buffer to be printed in reverse order or by figuring out where the most significant digit is and then calculating the digits from most significant to least significant. You can use a remainder operation, such as `x % 10`, to calculate the least significant digit of a number, and you can use division, such as `x / 10`, to remove that digit.
- One caveat is that, if the original number is negative, you have to be careful about calculating its digits. The `%` operator will return negative values. Some people attempt to deal with this by negating the integer if it is negative. However, if the number is the least possible `int`, this may overflow. E.g., in many C implementations, the least `int` value is -2,147,483,648, but it cannot be negated because the greatest `int` is 2,147,483,647.
- Any digit in numeric form (0 to 10) can be converted to a character (“0” to “9”) by adding `'0'`, such as `int d = x % 10; char c = d + '0';`. The C standard guarantees that this produces the appropriate character in `c`.
- After you obtain the characters from the digits, print them.

To print a `float` or `double`:

- Doing this completely correctly is hard, although it is a solved problem. The classic reference for it is [*Correctly Rounded Binary-Decimal and Decimal-Binary Conversions* by David M. Gay](http://ampl.com/REFS/rounding.pdf).
- If you just want a simple implementation suitable for a learning exercise, then you can format a floating-point value much as you would an integer: Calculate the digits individually. You also need to decide whether to print a fixed-point notation or a scientific notation (or other).
- To print a fixed-point notation, print the integer part of the value as above, for integer types. Then print a “.” and some digits for the fractional part of the value.
- To print a scientific notation, calculate the value of the exponent part (e.g., to express 12345789 as “1.23456789e7”, the exponent is 7, for 10<sup>7</sup>. Divide the value by 10 raised to the power of that exponent and print the resulting value as a fixed-point number (so, in this example, you print “1.23456789”), then print “e”, the print the exponent part.
- Floating-point rounding errors will occur in the above, making it suitable only for a learning exercise, not for use in a quality product.

The above should suffice to get you started. It is not complete code, obviously.

Comment: Minor: "digit in numeric form (0 to 10) can be converted to a character (“0” to “9”)" --> ""digit in numeric form (0 to 9) ..."

Answer (score 1):

just one thought, not very optimal:

```
int myvalue = 12345;
char buffer[100];
size_t index = 0;

while (myvalue) {
  buffer[index] = '0' + myvalue % 10;
  myvalue = myvalue / 10;
  index++;
}
buffer[index] = '\0';

reverse(buffer);
fprintf(stdout, buffer);
```

you have to consider the negative sign. And the sizeof buffer (100 is a very bad guess).

Comment: Modulo operator only works for integral types, user wants to do this with floats too, but clever try for a solution to probably a silly problem

Comment: with float you can do other number-crunching algorithms (use of logarithm f.e.)

Comment: That's true but you will be selecting your algorithm based on the data type, and OP seems to be asking for a way to do this without having to specify the data type.

Answer (score 0):

To print a `char` as a character use `fputc()`.

---

To print an integer (including `char`) in its decimal form, call either `print_unsigned()` or `print_signed()`, depending on if it is a signed integer or an unsigned integer.

The below uses recursion to print the most significant digits first.

For signed integers, it flips positive numbers to negative avoiding the undefined behavior of `-INT_MIN`.

```
int print_unsigned(uintmax_t x) {
  if (x >= 10) {
    if (print_unsigned(x / 10) == EOF) return EOF;
  }
  return fputc('0' + x % 10, stdout);
}

static int print_signed_helper(intmax_t x) {
  if (x <= -10) {
    if (print_signed_helper(x / 10) == EOF) return EOF;
  }
  return fputc('0' - x % 10, stdout);
}

int print_signed(intmax_t x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    if (fputc('-', stdout) == EOF) return EOF;
  } else {
    x = -x; // overflow not possible
  }
  return print_signed_helper(x);
}
```

The above stops early if the output causes an output error.  `EOF` is something rarely returned from `fputc()`.

---

To printf a `float` of `double`: TBD code.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that while it may be possible to hack something together that will do something RESEMBLING what you want (along the lines of Peter Miehle's solution posted in another answer), fundamentally C is not designed for this kind of functionality, and there is no support for it in the language.  What you want is function overloading, which C++ and many other higher-level languages provide.

Even Peter Miehle's solution cannot be implemented as a function (in C), because what kind of argument would the function take?  Either it is passed a type, in which case we KNOW the type and may as well use `printf`, or it is passed e.g. a void pointer, in which case, how can it implement the arithmetic operators without knowing the underlying data type the pointer points to?

Comment: This answer misinterprets the question. The question can be answered with algorithms that format C types such as `int` and `float` into strings containing numerals. It is not necessary to supply polymorphism or function overloading.